# Button size looked different

Tags: java, android, button

I want to place a `button` below another. But why does the size of the `button` look different after I add red color for the submit `button` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addClaims1"
            android:layout_width="334dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/claims"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="add claims" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:background="@color/indian_red"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/done"
        android:text="submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Between, is there a way to make the icon display near to the text ?

Comment: Certainly because of `android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"` in parent `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @Fllo  
I remove it but the size still look different..The submit button look bigger than add claims button

Comment: Maybe you need to remove padding and margins on button's widget. Otherwise, this is the image's button which has a padding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting background color of the button, you must assign a style to it. Make sure the resolution of both of the drawables are same to get similar sized buttons.

Xml Code for button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_custom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Custom Button"
    android:drawableRight="@mipmap/done"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme" />
```

And create this style:

```
<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/indian_red</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because the original button by default uses a background image that has transparent space near the border. You can also notice that the corners are rounded.

The buttons themselves are the same size actually.

In your case you should set a background to both images. You can also create images for that.

You can also notice that your "drawableRight" has margins on the first button and doesn't have them on the second. It is a thing called "Nine-path drawable" in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
```

from your LinearLayout.

Or add it into your second button if required

Comment: I remove it but the size still look different..The submit button look bigger than add claims button

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the `android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"` and  also `android:background="@color/indian_red"`.

**Solution:**

Give those buttons the same `style` like @Kartik Sharma said and then this is what that should look like after changing and setting it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addClaims1"
            android:layout_width="334dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="add claims" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:text="submit"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> is there a way to make the icon display near to the text ?

Yes.check this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btncat"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_category"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingEnd="40dp"
        android:paddingStart="20sp"
        android:text="@string/category"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Result:

[image]

Just play with these two:

```
android:paddingEnd="40dp"
android:paddingStart="20sp"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry I only can select one as an answer. Appreciate your help :)